# Compiler chooses the wrong operator<<

Tags: c++, g++

I have two libraries, one of which depends on the other. The first library defines some enumerations and provides an operator<<() that prints a short chunk of text for each enumeration. I have unit tests proving that this works.

The second library, which depends on the first, passes an enumeration value to std::cout (std::ostringstream behaves the same) and gets the corresponding numerical value rather than the text. No templated code is involved so it's not a template vs overload issue. I've looked through the preprocessor output to verify that the correct definitions are visible. I'm using g++ 4.1.2.

I'm unable to reproduce the problem outside of my libraries (which are thousands of lines), so I can't post any example code. My attempt to produce example code also convinces me that I understand how this is supposed to work. I'm guessing that something included in one of the headers is causing the compiler to make a different choice when selecting which operator<< to use.

My Question: How can I get insight into what choices the compiler has in choosing which version of the operator to use and why it picked the standard one over mine.

**Edit**: Adding signatures as requested:
Note though that this simplified example does not exhibit the problem.

*Header from the first library:*

```
namespace utcp {
  enum GainType {AGC_GAIN_MODE, MAN_GAIN_MODE };
}

// I've tried this passing the argument by value as well.
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const hdr::GainType &val)
{...}
```

*Code from the second libary*

```
std::cout << "Gain Text: " << hdr::AGC_GAIN_MODE << std::endl;
```

Comment: Is it an ADL related problem? Why not just post the signatures of the relevant operators and their arguments? Don't forget to include namespaces!

Comment: Originally I had a using namespace utcp, but removing it didn't help.

Comment: try adding the "operator<<" overload to your `utcp` namespace. Might fix the problem if its ADL related.

Comment: Did you try `http://www.gccxml.org`? It produces an XML file for your code, maybe this helps to find the problem.

Comment: Adding the operator to the utcp namespace *did* fix the problem! If you type that into an answer (hopefully with some explanation or a pointer to an explanation), I'll accept it.

Comment: Is the code in your example correct ? It does not look so (`hdr` vs `utcp`)

Comment: @JohnGordon: accept Dabid Rodriguez answer for this one, as he was faster to type a real answer, and i am to lazy to write an explanatory answer myself this time.

Comment: @smerlin: Sorry, I had not read your comment or the comment requesting that you added an answer. If you provide an answer and John accepts it I will delete mine (I cannot delete an accepted answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, as one of the comments mentions an Argument Dependent Lookup problem. When the compiler performs lookup for `std::cout << my_enum_variable` it will look in the current namespace, in the `std` namespace and the namespace where the type of `my_enum_variable` is defined. Only if there is no candidate, it will go up and search the enclosing namespaces. In this case, because any `enum` is implicitly convertible to `int` it will apply that conversion and not look in enclosing namespaces. The `using` directive does not help there.

The simple solution is moving the overloaded `operator<<` into the same namespace that the enumeration:

```
namespace utcp {
  enum GainType {AGC_GAIN_MODE, MAN_GAIN_MODE };
  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const GainType &val) {...}
}
```

This should enable ADL to pick you overload.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you upgrade to at least g++ 4.4 to get some [strongly-typed enumeration functionality](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf).

I recently upgraded to 4.6 and changed all my enums to enum class - I believe strong-typing will give you an idea as to the error in the code.

Comment: Believe me I wish I could, but between customer requirements and local IT policy, I'm stuck with what I've got.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to explicitly cast your argument to `<<` ?

Comment: I tried passing an enumeration constant. I also examined the variable type in gdb.